# CsvSimple with tabular: set specific number of rows

Tags: conditionals, csvsimple

For a `tabular` environment with `csvsimple` I would like to set the number of rows specifically.

This example is an attempt to show only the first two rows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
    name,surname,age
    Albert,Einstein,133
    Marie,Curie,145
    Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \csvreader[tabular=|l|l|c|,
    table head=\hline & Name & Age\\\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline]%
    {scientists.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname,age=\age}%
    {\ifnum\thecsvrow<2 \thecsvrow & \surname~\name & \age \else \fi}%
\end{document}
```

Should mention that I have little to no experience with `\ifnum`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several ways the achieve your goal. One would be to use the `filter` option to accept only the first two lines. `filter` uses the `ifthen` package syntax:

```
filter={\value{csvrow}<2}
```

The complete code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
    name,surname,age
    Albert,Einstein,133
    Marie,Curie,145
    Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \csvreader[tabular=|l|l|c|,
    table head=\hline & Name & Age\\\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline,
    filter={\value{csvrow}<2},
    ]%
    {scientists.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname,age=\age}%
    {\thecsvrow & \surname~\name & \age }%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, the `before filter` could be used to implement an own filter option. Here, `\ifnum` can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
    name,surname,age
    Albert,Einstein,133
    Marie,Curie,145
    Thomas,Edison,165
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
    \csvreader[tabular=|l|l|c|,
    table head=\hline & Name & Age\\\hline,
    late after line=\\\hline,
    before filter=\ifnum\thecsvrow<2\relax\csvfilteraccept\else\csvfilterreject\fi,
    ]%
    {scientists.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname,age=\age}%
    {\thecsvrow & \surname~\name & \age }%
\end{document}
```

Your attempt had not the expected result, because between `\ifnum` ... `\else` ... `\fi` you cannot have column separators `&`. This could be fixed to have the selection at this place, but you would get empty tabular lines instead of no lines.