# Skip rows in csvsimple

Tags: csvsimple

Similar to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316030/csvsimple-with-tabular-set-specific-number-of-rows) question, I need to skip some rows both from the top and bottom. For example, in this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Albert,Einstein,133
Marie,Curie,145
Thomas,Edison,165
X1, Y1, 1
X2, Y2, 2
X3, Y3, 3
X4, Y4, 4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|c|,
table head=\hline & Name & Age\\\hline,
late after line=\\\hline,
%filter={\value{csvinputline}>2},
%filter={\value{csvrow}<2},
]%
{scientists.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname,age=\age}%
{\thecsvrow & \surname~\name & \age }%
\end{document}
```

, I want to skip the first 2 rows and the last 3 rows. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To skip the last rows, you need to know the number of rows first. Therefore, you should count the rows with a first reader, and then display the table with a second reader.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{scientists.csv}
name,surname,age
Albert,Einstein,133
Marie,Curie,145
Thomas,Edison,165
X1, Y1, 1
X2, Y2, 2
X3, Y3, 3
X4, Y4, 4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Full table for comparison:

\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|c|,
table head=\hline & Name & Age\\\hline,
late after line=\\\hline,
]%
{scientists.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname,age=\age}%
{\thecsvrow & \surname~\name & \age }%


\bigskip
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
Reduced table (without the first 2 rows and the last 3 rows):

% count rows
\csvreader{scientists.csv}{}{}%
\edef\totalrows{\thecsvrow}

% show table
\csvreader[tabular=|l|l|c|,
table head=\hline & Name & Age\\\hline,
late after line=\\\hline,
filter expr={
      test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{3}}
  and test{\ifnumless{\thecsvinputline}{\totalrows-1}}
}]%
{scientists.csv}{name=\name,surname=\surname,age=\age}%
{\thecsvrow & \surname~\name & \age }%

\end{document}
```

The auxiliary macro `\totalrows` holds the total number of rows.

For filtering, I used some new features of `csvsimple` version `1.20` which allows to incorporate `etoolbox` expression, here:

```
filter expr={
      test{\ifnumgreater{\thecsvinputline}{3}}
  and test{\ifnumless{\thecsvinputline}{\totalrows-1}}
}
```

Using an older package version, you could alternatively use `ithen` syntax (also valid for the new version):

```
filter={
      \(\thecsvinputline>3\)
 \and \(\thecsvinputline<\numexpr\totalrows-1\relax\)
}
```