# Filtering in csvsimple by inequalities with row number

Tags: csvsimple

I am trying to make tables from a csv file with row ranges (e.g. 1st 25 rows, 2nd 25 rows, etc) using csvsimple.

I can get a table with the first n rows for various values of n by using a filter such as

```
filter={\value{csvrow}<25}
```

But if I reverse the inequality in the filter, e.g.

```
filter={\value{csvrow}>10}
```

I get a single blank row in the output table.

I have also tried using the minimal code in the example in the answer to [CsvSimple with tabular: set specific number of rows](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316030/csvsimple-with-tabular-set-specific-number-of-rows) and again, reversing the inequality does not work.

What am I doing wrong?